# How to control how many items are added in the carts during the test?

Tags: jmeter, performance

I am new to JMeter, so please bare with me.
Let's say I have a performance test with 100 v-users and I want to have at least 20 items in the cart / user. How can i control this in JMeter and where?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 3 options, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve:

1. [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - Loop Count - defines the number of iterations for each virtual user (affects all nested samplers)
2. [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - basically the same as above, but you can limit iterations to only those samplers which are required
3. [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - controls how many times (in absolute number values or percentages) children samplers are executed. See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more detailed explanation of the Throughput Controller and the [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

Answer (score 0):

To check 100 users login and each user need to have 20 items in their cart, you need to create a flow with Data Driven execution.
Preferable way is to create a excel/csv file and save all the 100 username and password in it.

1. Create HTTP request for Login API:- Fetch the first username & password and perform login.
2. Create HTTP request for Cart API: In the body, include all 20 items you want to have in that user`s Cart(If you dont want each user to have same items in Cart then create another excel/csv file containing several cart Items)

Put HTTP1 and HTTP2 in a for loop where condition will be end of the line or 100(whichever suites you)

Comment: I am trying to edit an already created test that functions properly - i tried to change the maximum cart items, but with no results. The search items are randomly generated - taken from a csv. Where can i edit to make the v-user add more than 1 item each in the cart?